# Get linked objects to MS Project tasks by custom Add-In

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-project

It is possible to insert an object into the Notes property of a task in MS Project. I insert for example an Excel file as a link in MS Project.

What I'm doing is reading tasks from MS Project file by C# and export them. I can get texts in the Notes property of the MS Project task by my Add-In, however I cannot find the Excel file that I have linked.

Do you know a way to access linked objects to MS Project tasks by C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searches and trying and trying I could not find and way to access linked objects defined in Notes property of the MS Project task.